# Can't access a variable from foreach in add_action

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to generate shortcodes from all of the fields on my ACF options page. The code I have gotten to now generates all of the shortcodes from `get_field_objects` by running `add_shortcode` in a foreach. However the variable `$name` won't return anything within the function. Is there any way I can call the variable within the function?

```
add_action('init', function(){
$fields = get_field_objects(options);
foreach( $fields as $field_name => $field ) {
    $name = $field['name'];
    $shortfun = function($name) {
        return $name;
    };
    add_shortcode($name, $shortfun);
}
});
```

Comment: When you assigned a function to a variable, shouldn't you be calling the function afterward for it to run? Like `$shortfun($name);`?

Comment: `$name` is being declared as a parameter of your shortcode callback; you're not actually passing in the value you've defined for `$name` on the line above it.